# Query System - How to search and display data?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need help on how to make the search function works based on the checkbox being ticked and display the results in the result page.
Basically, I have the database ready, the connection between the database and the web service has been made and the form is ready as well.

Below is my SearchPage.aspx.cs (the main page)

```
    public partial class SearchPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    protected void searchbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchbox = inputtxt.Text;            

        if (searchbox.Length == 0)
        {
            errormsglbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            errormsglbl.Text = "Please fill in the search box below";
        }

        else
        {

            string query = "SELECT * from item_list ";

            //fix this ?input = inputtxt.txt, title = title.......
            //if all are untick change all to true
            if (titlelbl.Checked)
                query += "WHERE Title like '%" + inputtxt.Text + "%'";
            else if (authorlbl.Checked)
                query += "WHERE Author = '%" + inputtxt.Text + "%'";
            else if (publisherlbl.Checked)
                query += "WHERE Publisher = '%" + inputtxt.Text + "%'";

            string connectionString =
                "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                "Data Source='C:\\Users\\Mister\\Documents\\Visual Studio
2012\\Project\\LibraryQuerySystem\\QuerySystem\\App_data\\items.mdb';";

            string queryString = "INSERT INTO item_list VALUES ('" + Title + "', '" +
Author + "', '" + Publisher + "')";

            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) 
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbConnection commandText = queryString;
                //OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
                OleDbDataReader reader = commandText.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    result+="Title = "+ reader["Title"].ToString()+"  ";
                    result+="Author= "+ reader["Author"].ToString()+"  ";
                    result+="Publisher= "+ reader["Publisher"].ToString()+"  ";
                    result+"<br/>";//dd new line
                }
                reader.Close();
                connection.Close();

                //set Session here
                Session["Results"]=ResultPage;
                //now redirect
                Response.Redirect("~/ResultPage.aspx");
            }

        }

    }

    protected void addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("/AddPage.aspx");
    }

    protected void authorlbl_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void publisherlbl_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void inputtxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

this is my ResultPage.aspx.cs

```
public partial class ResultPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        results.InnerHtml = Session["Results"].ToString();

    }

    protected void backbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("/SearchPage.aspx");
    }

}
```

and my DatabaseService.asmx.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Databases
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", Name="Library Database",
Description="This is Database of the Library")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment
the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Databases : System.Web.Services.WebService
{        
    [WebMethod]
    public string CheckConnection()
    {
            string result = "";
            string connectionString =
                "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                "Data Source='C:\\Users\\Mister\\Documents\\Visual Studio
2012\\Projects\\LibraryQuerySystem\\QuerySystem\\App_data\\items.mdb';";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                result = "Connection Success";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                result = "Error in Connection";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string addBook(String title, String author, String publisher)
    {
        string result = "";

        string connectionString =
            "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
            "Data Source='C:\\Users\\Mister\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Project
\\LibraryQuerySystem\\QuerySystem\\App_data\\items.mdb';";

        string queryString = "INSERT INTO item_list VALUES ('" + title + "', '" +
author + "', '" + publisher + "')";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = queryString;
            // OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();

            result += "Item added";
        }
        return result;
    }




    [WebMethod]
    public string[] searchBook(string input, Boolean title, Boolean author, Boolean
publisher)
    {

        string connectionString =
            "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
            "Data Source='C:\\Users\\Mister\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Project
\\LibraryQuerySystem\\QuerySystem\\App_data\\items.mdb';";

        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM item_list WHERE Title = '" + input + "' OR
Author = '" + input + "' OR Publisher = '" + input + "'";

        string lists = "";

        string[] book = new string[3];

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = queryString;

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
            }

            if (title == true)
            {
                queryString = "SELECT * FROM item_list WHERE Title like '%" + input +
"%'";

                OleDbCommand comd2 = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
                comd2.CommandText = queryString;
                OleDbDataReader read2 = comd2.ExecuteReader();

                while (read2.Read())
                {
                    lists += "<p> title = " + read2[0].ToString() + "<br> author = " +
read2[1].ToString() + "<br> publisher = " + read2[2].ToString() + "</p>";
                }
            }

            if (author == true)
            {
                queryString = "SELECT * FROM item_list WHERE Author LIKE '%" + input +
"%'";

                OleDbCommand comd3 = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
                comd3.CommandText = queryString;
                OleDbDataReader read3 = comd3.ExecuteReader();

                while (read3.Read())
                {
                    lists += "<p> title = " + read3[0].ToString() + "<br> author = " +
read3[1].ToString() + "<br> publisher = " + read3[2].ToString() + "</p>";
                }
            }

            if (publisher == true)
            {
                queryString = "SELECT * FROM item_list WHERE Publisher LIKE '%" + input +
"%'";

                OleDbCommand comd4 = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
                comd4.CommandText = queryString;
                OleDbDataReader read4 = comd4.ExecuteReader();

                while (read4.Read())
                {
                    lists += "<p> title = " + read4[0].ToString() + "<br> author = " +
read4[1].ToString() + "<br> publisher = " + read4[2].ToString() + "</p>";
                }
            }

            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();
        }
        return book;
    }
}
```

The problem I have is in the Search Page, which is in these lines:

2.The name 'Author' does not exist in the current context
3.The name 'Publisher' does not exist in the current context

```
            string queryString = "INSERT INTO item_list VALUES ('" + Title + "', '" +
Author + "', '" + Publisher + "')";
```

4.Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Data.OleDbConnection'
5.'System.Data.OleDbConnection' does not contain a definition for "ExecuteReader' and no extension method 'ExecuteReader' accepting first argument of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection' could be found

```
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) 
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbConnection commandText = queryString;
                //OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
                OleDbDataReader reader = commandText.ExecuteReader();
```

6.The name 'result' does not exist in the current context
9.Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

```
while (reader.Read())
                {
                    result+="Title = " reader["Title"].ToString()+"  ";
                    result+="Author= " reader["Author"].ToString()+"  ";
                    result+="Publisher= " reader["Publisher"].ToString()+"  ";
                    result+"<br/>";//dd new line
                }
```

Please help me find the solution.

Comment: i think you are invoking same query  multiple times....

Comment: Ok I forgot to update those. Just updated the post. Would love to know what else is wrong with my coding. I am just a beginner, after all.
Appreciate it if you could point out the steps that are needed to be taken, especially the search function and displaying the data.

Comment: well you want to fire a query based on selected checkbox right?

Comment: Yes. and to display the results on the ResultPage as well. Please help!

Comment: well can you post your design code aswell so that it is easy to resolve the issue...

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding:

1.you have an Input `TextBox` to read the `input String` basically it is an search string.
2.you have 3 `CheckBox` Controls.
They are :

a.Author
b.Publisher
c.Title

3.based on the user selection the query has to be fired with given input string.

**Example** : if user wants to search `Title` he has to enter `some title` on input `TextBox` and `select/Check` the `Title CheckBox` to find the `Books` with given `Title`.
same for `Publisher` and `Author`

Try This Code: (Sample Code)

**Design Code:**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkTitle" runat="server" Text="Title"/>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAuthor" runat="server" Text="Author" />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPublisher" runat="server" Text="Publisher" />
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtInput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
```

**Code Behind:**

```
    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            String query = "SELECT * FROM item_list ";

            if(chkTitle.Checked)
            query+="WHERE Title like '%" + txtInput.Text + "%'";
            else if(chkAuthor.Checked)
            query+="WHERE Author = '%" + txtInput.Text + "%'";
            else if(chkPublisher.Checked)
            query+="WHERE Publisher = '%" + txtInput.Text + "%'";

            //now execute command with  query variable to perform search 
string connectionString =
            "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
            "Data Source='C:\\Users\\Mister\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Project
\\LibraryQuerySystem\\QuerySystem\\App_data\\items.mdb';";

        string queryString = "INSERT INTO item_list VALUES ('" + title + "', '" +
author + "', '" + publisher + "')";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = queryString;
            // OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
              result+="Title = "+ reader["Title"].ToString()+"  ";
              result+="Author= "+ reader["Author"].ToString()+"  ";
              result+="Publisher= "+ reader["Publisher"].ToString()+"  ";
              result+"<br/>";//dd new line
            }
            connection.Close();

           //set Session here
           Session["Results"]=result;
           //now redirect
           Response.Redirect("~/SearchPage.aspx");
        }

        }
```

Now `SearchPage.aspx` page should contain following code:

**Design code of SearchPage.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SearchPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="SearchPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="results" runat="server">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code Behind of  `SearchPage` page**

Page_Load should add the results to the div element

```
public partial class SearchPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        results.InnerHtml = Session["Results"].ToString();
    }
}
```

**Solution 3:**  you need concatenation operator `+` for combining string

Try This:

```
while (reader.Read())
                {
                    result+="Title = "+ reader["Title"].ToString()+"  ";
                    result+="Author= "+ reader["Author"].ToString()+"  ";
                    result+="Publisher= "+ reader["Publisher"].ToString()+"  ";
                    result+"<br/>";//dd new line
                }
```

Note: as this is a sample Code I hope that you can change your code as per your reuirement, if you need something else please let me know.

Comment: Thanks those are indeed helpful, but I wanna know how to display the result to the ResultPage.

Comment: @user3051306 : on which control you want to display the results? like grid view or some thing like that.

Comment: Oh I don't use grid view. I will be using Label. :\
So it will display all the data into the label placed in the ResultPage.
Do I have to write some codes to connect these 2 pages?

Comment: @user3051306 : are you really using Label to display the results because its not a good practice to use label for diplaying results as if the results contains huge records then it would be a problem right.

Comment: I'm thinking of using div and innerhtml for now to display the results. :\

Comment: @user3051306 : Okay that's fine... so now you want to display the results on div tag right? in same page or new page?

Comment: In a new page. Which is the ResultPage.aspx.cs form that I have.
Looking forward to receiving your reply.
Thx in adv.

Comment: @user3051306 : check my detailed edited answer hope it helps you , mark it as answer if it helps you :)

Comment: The results should be displayed in the ResultPage.aspx though, not in the SearchPage.aspx, so I assume that's what you meant. I have edited my codes above using your answer, I am now having a problem with the "reader" in the SearchPage. Please refer back to my edited post above. Looking forward to receiving your reply.

Comment: @user3051306: yes i meant Results.aspx sorry for that, sorry it was my mistake , i forgot to add `+` to combine strings, see my edited answer with section `Solution3`.

Comment: ok right after adding the + sign, 11 errors occur. 1.The name 'title' does not exist in the current context. Same goes to author and publisher. 4.Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Data.OleDbConnection'. 6.The name 'result' does not exist in the current context. 11.'QuerySystem.ResultPage' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'. :\

Comment: @user3051306 : whatever the code i have given you is sample code so that you can change according to your requirement. please change author , title , publisher into your proper db columns.

Comment: @user3051306 : okay you can send me mail

Comment: What's your email? Thanks in advance

Comment: you can send it to `Sudhakar.Tillapudi@gmail.com`